# Operation between jTextfield arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I want to check if the number of SN between startSN and endSN equals to numSN, but I want to ignore the  `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`  for empty JTextField :

```
private javax.swing.JTextField StartSN0,StartSN1,StartSN2,EndSN0,EndSN1,EndSN2,num0,num1,num2;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox0,jCheckBox1,jCheckBox2;

JTextField sTF[] = new JTextField[]{StartSN0,StartSN1,StartSN2};    
JTextField eTF[] = new JTextField[]{EndSN0,EndSN1,EndSN2};

long startSN[] = {Long.parseLong(StartSN0.getText()),Long.parseLong(StartSN1.getText()),Long.parseLong(StartSN2.getText())};
long endSN[] = {Long.parseLong(EndSN0.getText()),Long.parseLong(EndSN1.getText()),Long.parseLong(EndSN2.getText())};
long numSN[] = {Long.parseLong(num0.getText()),Long.parseLong(num1.getText()),Long.parseLong(num2.getText())};  
JCheckBox [] cbox = new JCheckBox[]{jCheckBox0,jCheckBox1,jCheckBox2};

for (int i = 0;i<=3;i++){
    long matching = endSN[i] - startSN[i] + 1;
    if (sTF[i] != null && eTF[i] != null ){
        if (sTF[i].getText().trim().length() != 12 || eTF[i].getText().trim().length() != 12)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter valid SN");
        else if (matching == numSN[i])
            cbox[i].setSelected(true);
        else
            cbox[i].setSelected(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `startSN0` and please add complete stack trace.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: And what is your question? Do you understand why an empty String will lead to a `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: I want the code to ignore when all other JTextField are empty.

Comment: Well, then you can either check for empty strings before parsing, or catch the exception. Either way, you'll have to add code describing what should happen in this case. Note that there might also be other input Strings that could lead to `NumberFormatExceptions`.

Comment: I tried catching the exception but it ran with no result (the checkbox has not been selected).

Comment: `I want to ignore the java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` do not ignore it. Prevent it: check if string is "" before parsing.